# sklearn Perceptron incorrectly training on tiny 3 point linearly separable 2D dataset?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, perceptron

```
from sklearn.linear_model import Perceptron
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_predictions_and_data(X, y_obs, model):
    min_x1 = np.min(X[:, 0])
    max_x1 = np.max(X[:, 0])

    min_x2 = np.min(X[:, 1])
    max_x2 = np.max(X[:, 1])

    x1, x2 = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(0, max_x1 * 1.2, 500),
                     np.linspace(0, max_x2 * 1.2, 500))
        
    y_pred = model.predict(np.c_[x1.ravel(), x2.ravel()])
    y_pred = y_pred.reshape(x1.shape)    
    
    cs = plt.contourf(x1, x2, y_pred, alpha = 0.4)
    plt.gca().scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c = y_obs, edgecolor='black')
    
X = np.array([[2, 4], [8, 2], [10, 5]])
y_obs = np.array([0, 0, 1])

psmall = Perceptron()
psmall.fit(X, y_obs)
print(psmall.predict(X))
plot_predictions_and_data(X, y_obs, psmall)
```

When I tried training an sklearn Perceptron classifier (code above) on very simple data, I got decision boundaries that don't make sense, shown below:

[image: weird sklearn Perceptron output]

Running the perceptron fit with `verbose=1` didn't really give me any insight. I think I must be missing something very basic and important.

Comment: `psmall = LogisticRegression()` works

Comment: This is actually basically what I'm curious about! I thought I understood the relationship between Perceptrons and logistic regression, but the fact that the Perceptron is failing here makes me think there's something very important that I'm not understanding.

Comment: yes, I spent about 20 min on it now, and have no idea what was happening.... may be it is running on regression mode not classification mode? I am using R most of the time...

Comment: @gunes could you provide any help?

Comment: Interesting that increasing `n_iter_no_change` at least "fixes" this example.